# How to safely pass post_id and user_id via AJAX to the backend (prevent user from changing it via JS)?

Tags: ajax, javascript, security

I'm having code (user rates post) where I'm passing user_id and post_id via AJAX to the back-end. My concern is that user can change values in JS and pass another’s `user id` or `post id`. How do I prevent that?

Here is a simplified code (without nonces for the sake of example):

```
$('input[name="rate1"]:radio').change(function () {
    var rating = $("input[name='rate1']:checked").val();

    $.ajax({
        url : '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>',
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            'action': 'rate_the_post',
            'post_id': <?php echo $post_id; ?>,
            'user_id': <?php echo $user_id; ?>,
            'rating' : rating
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

In the backend I get variables and update the post based on them:

```
function rate_post() {
    global $wpdb;

    $post_id = intval($_POST['post_id']);
    $user_id = intval($_POST['user_id']);
    $rating = intval($_POST['rating']);

    ...update DB with $wpdb;
}
```

So how do I make sure I have a valid `user_id` of current user and `post_id` of current post in the backend?

Comment: if a user is logged in, you don't need to submit her/his ID, since that variable is available in php anyways..?!

Comment: @honk31 i don't think it's available via AJAX call, but if yes, how would you get it?

Comment: when the user is logged in, you could get its ID and credentials inside functions.php (or a plugin for that matter) via `wp_get_current_user()` or ID only via `get_current_user_id()`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm logging user via AJAX, so I don't have that available in functions.php

Comment: eather way, the user has to be logged in to vote, correct? so it will be available once s/he is..

Comment: @Runnick AJAX is just the means by which you communicate with the server. WordPress already knows who's logged in, so it doesn't make sense for your form to send information that the server already knows. As for `post_id` - as long as the user is set in stone, it doesn't really matter if they tamper with the message en route to the server, does it? Just validate the post ID on the backend - make sure the user can actually vote on that item. Worst case scenario, then, users add votes to posts they're not looking at. You could use a NONCE to further secure the post ID

Comment: @bosco the problem was I was logging user with AJAX with no page reload so I thought my only option is to get `user_id` from `wp_signon()` return and pass it as AJAX response to JS. But then I found I can use `set_current_user()` and then get that user in backend in next AJAX calls. I will edit the question to reflect this and then will add an answer.